.ignoreSafeArea() disable DragGesture
Hi everyone I'm trying to create a Crop View for cropping images selected by the user through the use of PhotoPicker
The UI seems perfect and the implementations of the various gestures also seem to work as I want but I have a problem... The mask located above the image respects the safe area, however I need its dimensions to be equivalent to the device.
I tried to enter .ignoreSafeArea() but this disables the DragGesture and I can't figure out how to solve this problem.. I need the mask to ignore the device's safe area but it shouldn't disable the DragGesture... it's definitely a problem of overlapping views but I can't understand where I'm wrong..
struct DraggableImageView: View {
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    @State private var lastOffset = CGSize.zero
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1.0 // Scala iniziale dell'immagine (100%)
    @State private var lastScale: CGFloat = 0
    @GestureState private var isInteractionActive = false // Stato dell'interazione
    
    let selectedPhoto: UIImage // Immagine selezionata
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            let size = geometry.size
            let imageSize: CGFloat = size.width * 0.9  // 90% della larghezza, dimensione del cerchio
            
            ZStack {
                // Maschera circolare
                Rectangle()
                    .strokeBorder(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                    .frame(width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
                    .overlay(
                        Image(uiImage: selectedPhoto)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()  // Riempie la maschera circolare
                            .offset(offset)
                            .scaleEffect(scale) // Applica il fattore di zoom
                            .frame(width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
                    )

                // Overlay per l'interazione
                Color.black.opacity(isInteractionActive ? 0.3 : 0.7)
                    .mask {
                        Rectangle()
                            .overlay {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .frame(width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
                                    .blendMode(.destinationOut)  // Maschera fuori dalla zona circolare
                            }
                    }
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .updating($isInteractionActive, body: { _, out, _ in
                                out = true
                            })
                            .onChanged { value in
                                let translation = value.translation
                                offset = CGSize(width: lastOffset.width + translation.width, height: lastOffset.height + translation.height)
                            }
                            .onEnded { _ in
                                // Calcolare i limiti per evitare che l'immagine esca dal cerchio
                                let imageWidth = imageSize * scale
                                
                                // Limiti di spostamento (non devono superare il cerchio)
                                let maxOffsetX = ((imageWidth - imageSize) / 2) / scale
                                let maxOffsetY = ((imageWidth - imageSize) / 2) / scale
                                
                                // Impedire che l'immagine esca dal cerchio
                                offset.width = min(max(offset.width, -maxOffsetX), maxOffsetX)
                                offset.height = min(max(offset.height, -maxOffsetY), maxOffsetY)
                                
                                lastOffset = offset  // Salva l'offset finale
                            }
                    )
                    .gesture(
                        MagnificationGesture()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                // Limitiamo lo zoom minimo a garantire che l'immagine non sia mai più piccola del cerchio
                                scale = max(1.0, min(value, 3.0)) // Limita la scala tra 100% e 300%
                            }
                            .onEnded { _ in
                                // Quando lo zoom finisce, non cambiamo più i limiti
                            }
                    )
            }
           .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
        .background(.black)
    }
}


There is no ignoreSafeArea in your code.

@Sweeper.. excuse me ... I edited my question

I solved it... the problem was that the gestures were separate... For proper functioning, both gestures must be implemented in SimultaneousGesture like this:
Color.black.opacity(isInteractionActive ? 0.3 : 0.7)
                    .mask {
                        Rectangle()
                            .overlay {
                                Circle()
                                    .frame(width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
                                    .blendMode(.destinationOut)
                            }
                    }
                    .gesture(
                        SimultaneousGesture(
                            MagnificationGesture()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                let updateScale = value + lastScale
                                scale = (updateScale < 1 ? 1 : updateScale)
                            }
                            .onEnded({ value in
                                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2)) {
                                    let imageWidth = imageSize * scale
                                    let maxOffsetX = ((imageWidth - imageSize) / 2) / scale
                                    let maxOffsetY = ((imageWidth - imageSize) / 2) / scale
                                    offset.width = min(max(offset.width, -maxOffsetX), maxOffsetX)
                                    offset.height = min(max(offset.height, -maxOffsetY), maxOffsetY)
                                    
                                    lastOffset = offset
                                }
                                if scale < 1 {
                                    scale = 1
                                    lastScale = 0
                                    
                                } else {
                                    lastScale = scale - 1
                                }
                                
                            }), DragGesture()
                                .updating($isInteractionActive, body: { _, out, _ in
                                    out = true
                                })
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    let translation = value.translation
                                    offset = CGSize(width: lastOffset.width + translation.width, height: lastOffset.height + translation.height)
                                }
                                .onEnded { _ in
                                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2)) {
                                        let imageWidth = imageSize * scale
                                        let maxOffsetX = ((imageWidth - imageSize) / 2) / scale
                                        let maxOffsetY = ((imageWidth - imageSize) / 2) / scale
                                        
                                        offset.width = min(max(offset.width, -maxOffsetX), maxOffsetX)
                                        offset.height = min(max(offset.height, -maxOffsetY), maxOffsetY)
                                        
                                        lastOffset = offset  // Salva l'offset finale
                                    }
                                })
                       
                    )
                    

